# Tailwind classes Not Working in nuxt app?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I created a nuxt app and chose Tailwind as the UI framework. Up to this point when I add a class it is working fine, but when I added a tailwind.config.js using  the `npx tailwindcss init` command . Suddenly the tailwind classes stopped working only if I add any custom ones in the config file. I tried deleting the config file to see if the classes would work again and they did. this is what my config file looks like

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [    './pages/**/*.{html,js,vue}',
  './components/**/*.{html,js,vue}'],
  theme: {
    colors: {
      'raisin' : '#262730',
      'test' : '#D8B4E2'
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Suddenly the tailwind classes stopped working only if I add any custom ones in the config file.

Assuming the "Tailwind classes" you referred to are Tailwind classes involving color values, then it is because you have defined your own colors in `theme.colors` which completely replace Tailwind default colors. You may have meant to define your custom colors in `theme.extend.colors`, which would **merge** them into the Tailwind default colors:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [    './pages/**/*.{html,js,vue}',
  './components/**/*.{html,js,vue}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'raisin' : '#262730',
        'test' : '#D8B4E2'
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed it, I wasnt aware that I was overwriting the tailwind colours. Thanks alot for the help!